# How to document interface key type with JSDoc?

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

Let's say I got an interface like this:

```
interface Foo {
  [barKey: string]: boolean;
}

// or as a type

type Foo = {
  [barKey: string]: boolean;
}
```

Then I initialize a variable with this type:

```
const myObj: Foo = {
  "hello": false,
  "world": true,
}
```

How do I make it so the editor (VSCode/IntellIJ/any which supports JSDoc) picks up the JSDoc for the key when I hover over it? I've tried something like this:

```
/**
 * A cool interface
 */
interface Foo {
  /**
   * Some hints about the property
   */
  [barKey: string]: boolean;
}
```

However this unfortunately does not work, I've also tried it like this:

```
/**
 * A cool interface
 */
interface Foo {
  [
    /**
     * Some hints about the property
     */
    barKey: string
  ]: boolean
}
```

But with no success, any way in which this would work?

TL;DR: How to document every object key if derived from an interface where the key type is specified, so that the editor picks it up when hovering over the key?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it must depend on your IDE/editor. Your first example works perfectly in WebStorm 2022.1.2. There is no other way to define an interface key, as far as I am aware.

I guess the alternative is to just include the keys as bullet points in your interface definition. That way, you can at least get them when you hover over that.